# Graceful shutdown Spring integration application when current messages processed

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have an application which reads the data from JMS message queue and after reading the message message passed to diff async channel ( executor channels). When I stop the application it stops processing the message currently in flight and throw the error

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89).
```

Is there any way the application can be gracefully shut down?

I am already using `registerShutdownHook()` on application context.

Comment: Please, learn how to ask questions here properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation about Orderly Shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#jmx-shutdown).

> As described in "MBean Exporter", the MBean exporter provides a JMX operation called stopActiveComponents, which is used to stop the application in an orderly manner. The operation has a single Long parameter. The parameter indicates how long (in milliseconds) the operation waits to allow in-flight messages to complete. The operation works as follows: ...

**However, async handoff and JMS will risk message loss.**

Concurrency is best managed by the listener container.

Comment: Async with JMS can cause message loss.

Comment: you mean to say Orderly shutdown will not work?

Comment: It will work; it is just that as soon as you hand off to another thread, the JMS message will be acknowledged and if the system crashes at that time, you will lose the message; it's best to process the message entirely on the container thread.